# problem in writting a hello world programme

Tags: java

Error: Main method not found in the file, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0z4Q.jpg)

Comment: Please always, always show code as *text* rather than as a screenshot or (worse) a photo of a screen. The `main` method you've provided won't compile because you're using `system` instead of `System`, and `string` instead of `String`.

Answer (score 2):

**S** should be uppercase in both `String` and `System`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FirstClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println("Hello world");
    }
}
```

String is an immutable class in Java and S should be capital --> **String**
System is also a class name and S should be capital  --> **System**